# Get folder structure along with folder/file sizes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

After doing my research for this specific task I found at that most of the solution given for this kind of problem either return the list of all the files or the TOTAL size of the folder/file.

What I am trying to achieve is get an output in the CSV file stating the folder structure i.e. folders - sub folders - files (optional) along with the size information for EACH.

There is no specific format for the CSV. I just need to know the tree structure with the size of the folder/sub-folder.

The reason behind this is that we are moving from physical servers to the cloud. In order to verify whether all the data was retained correctly during conversion I need to make a similar list of all SHARED DRIVES which can later be validated.

Looking forward for meaningful insights. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Sooo, that should be what you are asking for:

```
import os
import csv

def sizeof_fmt(num, suffix='B'):
    for unit in ['','K','M','G','T','P','E','Z']:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f%s%s" % (num, unit, suffix)
        num /= 1024.0
    return "%.1f%s%s" % (num, 'Yi', suffix)

def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return sizeof_fmt(total_size)

with open("yourfilename.csv", mode="w") as dir_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(dir_file, delimiter=",")

    def files_and_sizes(start_path):
        dir_list = [file for file in os.listdir(start_path)]
        for file in dir_list:
            path = start_path + "\\" + file
            if os.path.isdir(path) is True:
                csv_writer.writerow([file, get_size(path)])
                files_and_sizes(start_path + "\\" + file)

    files_and_sizes(r"C:\your\path\here")
```

*Updated to better fit the question.*

---

You can get all files with sizes like this:

```
import os

all_files_with_size = []

def files_and_sizes(start_path):
    dir_list = [file for file in os.listdir(start_path)]
    current_dir = []
    for file in dir_list:
        path = start_path + "\\" + file
        if os.path.isdir(path) is True:
            current_dir.append(files_and_sizes(path))
        else:
            current_dir.append((file, os.lstat(path).st_size))
    return current_dir
```

It will return a list containing all files like (file, size) and a sublist for each directory.
I recommend appending the entries to a file, but the formatting is up to you.

Also, if you want the directory sizes as well:

```
if os.path.isdir(path) is True:
        current_dir.append(file, os.lstat(path).st_size)
        current_dir.append(files_and_sizes(path))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Though I am getting the following error for the last block of code (to get directory sizes as well) - append takes only 1 argument, 2 given. I actually will only require all the folders and subfolders sizes and not the file size. Also, the current size displayed is in bytes (I guess) how can I change it to a readable format like kb, MB, GB etc. In the end I just want all this data to be written into a csv file. Thanks and sorry for being a pain in the ass.

Comment: Works Great. But now I think CSV is not a very good option for nested data. Do you suggest such data to be stored as XML or JSON?

Comment: Sorry, for the late answer. I'd go for XML and make a container for every subdirectory.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will have to use a combination of the solutions that you have already found. Such as 'os.listdir(path)' to get the contents of a directory, 'os.lstat(path).st_size' to get file size, and 'os.path.isdir(path)' and 'os.path.isfile(path)' to determine the type.